# Knockout.js: Looping through an array with placeholders

Tags: knockout.js

I loop through an array of events inserting a thumbnail-template for each of them:

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'eventThumb', foreach: events}"></ul>
```

Now I want to insert 1 or 2 placeholders if a row of 3 is not complete:

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'eventThumb', foreach: events}">
    <li data-bind="visible: events().length % 3 > 0">
       <div class="empty-block no-event"></div>
    </li>
    <li data-bind="visible: events().length % 3 > 1">
       <div class="empty-block no-event"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However my placeholder are always visible. Neither seem any data-bind statements work. I was checking the knockout-context on these elements and it seems intact.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Leon

Comment: can you explain more your purpose, your html is the same in 2 li

Comment: It's not really the same. I have several rows of thumbnails, 3 per each row. Now, I want the last row to have exactly 3 elements. If my array of events does not fill in, I want to put a placeholder to complete the row. That's why I'm using the modulo: length % 3 > 0 and length % 3 > 1

Comment: so to be clear, you have list of events and you want to insert thumbnail-template for each item, but in the last rows if it has less than 3 events then you 'll fill it with some empty block ?

Comment: exactly. 1 or 2 empty blocks respectively

Answer (score 0):

I think the body of the ul isn't evaluated because it contains a template. Maybe it's an option to change it to divs?

```
<div>
    <ul data-bind="template: {name: 'eventThumb', foreach: events}"></ul>
    <div data-bind="visible: events().length % 3 > 0">
       <div class="empty-block no-event"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: events().length % 3 > 1">
       <div class="empty-block no-event"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise you might have to add the placeholders to the template `eventThumb`, and add an extra condition to the `visible` so it's only applied to the last loop (have a look at `$index`).

Also, if you're in a foreach, you need to call `$root.events()` or `$parent.events()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right: the ul-body is not evaluated at all. No data-bind statements work. The div-solution could work, but it's tricky to align the ul and the divs in one row. The UL and the template with LI are reusable modules within the project, so I'm reluctant to change the HTML and CSS there. I was also trying to use the comment style of knockout: <!-- ko: template ..... But it does not seem to work either.